# creating table inside mysql database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am trying to learn how to create tables inside a mysql database.My code is only for learning purpose.My approact is

1.User will register to the website.

2.a database will be created whenever a user register,(i mean a database per user and database name will be exactly similar to the username). Whether it is a good or bad approach that's another question. I am not seeking any suggestion about this.

3.After creating database successfully php will call Table::make() class which will create a table having some specified fields.(problem lies here)

Database is successfully created but problem is no table is being generated inside that particular database.No error message has been given either.What might be the situation here?how i can solve this.

The process takes some time to do the tase.What might be the reason for this delay.( i mean i can see the browser reloading for 3-4 seconds to complete the task when i click register button)

```
  class Table{

     public static function make($fields){

        try{
            print_r($fields);
            $pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname={$fields['username']}",'root','');
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE userinfo (
                   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                   username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                   password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
                   salt VARCHAR(50),
                   name VARCHAR(50),
                   reg_date TIMESTAMP,
                   group INT(11)
                   )";
            $ready=$pdo->prepare($sql);
            $ready->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'bal';
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

     }
  }
```

Comment: its such a bad idea. 10,000 and more than users registered in your site than it create 10,000 and  more Db.

Comment: it was single database for every users first,But when i planned to experiment with a blog site then i thought there will be posts from every user and likes and comments.How can i manage all that in one or two databases?

Comment: give relationship in table. Relationship concept is help to manage your users.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach i.e creating a **Database for each user is not Good**. 
Even creating separate table for each user will be very complex. As you have already mentioned it is Blog site and each user will be having post, comment etc.

The usual answer is that "table per user" is a horrible design, and the simple solution is a single table with an extra field(s) to identify ownership.

e.g. having

```
table_1   table_2    table_3 ...... table_999999999
id        id         id             id
...       ...        ...            ...
```

is a massive waste of resources, whereas having

```
table
id
user
...
```

is far easier to represent.

Your data will look like
Table `User`

```
userid  Name    ....
1       Alex    ....
2       Bob     ....
```

Table `Post`

```
userid  postid  posttext
1       1       Hello First Post of User 1
1       2       Hello, 2nd Post of User 1
2       3       Hello, First post of User 2
```

and Select query will also be very simple.

if you want to select a post from particular user you can use

```
select * from Post where userid=1.
```

And This is MySql. even you have 1 million record in a table it wont be a problem to fetch. 
If you want to optimize you can learn how to create `Indexe`.

Comment: thanx.! very useful..i will surely look into that :)